# How to get tweets older than 7 days using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I have written code to pull tweets on certain key words and send it to an excel document. I am trying to get it to work with the premium sandbox but cannot figure out how. Any insight?

I have:

-a developer account

-a registered application

-a developer environment set up

what else do I need to do to get this to work? Core code is as follows:

```
##import library
import os
import tweepy as tw
        ###variables###

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
##set values for keys

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
search_list = ["apples oranges -filter:retweets"]
search_words = search_list[sc]
date_since = "2020-07-01"
##set search words and search date limit



def gettweet():
    
    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                  q=search_words,
                  lang="en", since=date_since,until="2020-07-16",tweet_mode="extended").items(50)
                #finds tweets. can filter our retweets if wanted
                #,until="2020-07-08"

    all_tweets = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.location, tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text] for tweet in tweets]
    print(all_tweets)
#generates list containin username and location

gettweet()
```

From this I hope to return a dataframe containing tweets containing the keywords 'apples' or 'oranges'. I want these tweets to be from 30 days ago (hence my using the premium sandbox for this)

Comment: There is far too much code here. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Fixed

Comment: Better, but the `pandas` and `openpxyl` code is still irrelevant to the problem. Also, you don't show what output you're getting, and what you were expecting.

Comment: @RodBentrich can you share the final code? the updated one? many thanks.